# PYTHON Lib:bs4 | Need help getting distinct url

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I cant figure out how to get distinct URL value on my code.
Could you help me out to solve this problem?

[**Source HTML**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLCxr.png)

**Code:**

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://cointelegraph.com/tags/bitcoin').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='post-preview-item-inline'):
    title = div.find(class_='post-preview-item-inline__title')
    print(title.text)
    body = div.find(class_='post-preview-item-inline__text')
    print(body.text)
    for link in div.select('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

**Result:**

```
Why Bitcoin Price Is Headed to 7-Month Low If $7K Support Fails 
 Bitcoin price continues to yield to bears and could collapse to $6.5K or below if $7,080 and $6,800 fail to hold as support. 
https://cointelegraph.com/news/why-bitcoin-price-is-headed-to-7-month-low-if-7k-support-fails
https://cointelegraph.com/news/why-bitcoin-price-is-headed-to-7-month-low-if-7k-support-fails
javascript:void(0);
```

**Goal:**
I want to show only 1 URL not 2 as displayed above in the result. 
Also I would like to know how to remove `javascript:void(0);` as well.

Thanks

Comment: You're printing the `href` of all `a` elements - apparently the website you're parsing has multiple. What is your problem exactly? How do you know which link you want if there's multiple? And if you can answer that, how would you try to code that?

Comment: Both links are the same, just in 2 different classes.

The thing is that the link shows up 2 times in the HTML
[Website HTML][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX5Ce.png

They have 2 different classes:
class=post-preview-item-inline__title-wrp
class=post-preview-item-inline

But I am not sure how to filter by this class.

Comment: You're using `print(links.get('href'))` as well as `print(link.get('href'))`; trying getting rid of the first.

Comment: @JackFleeting ( forgot to remove that one in the example, I edited the code on stack now ) but the issue still stands. I only use it only once in my code that you can see the result off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.select` which allows css selectors. Just like you would in css, this is how you can select the specific link with the appropriate class:

```
for link in div.select('.post-preview-item-inline__figure-link'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```